# How to redirect page after confirmation in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Say a user clicks a link to a page that is protected. They are then redirected to a sign in screen where they can log in. If they do, then are successfully redirected to that page. But if they don't have an account they have to sign up. This is where things get tricky because I'm doing an email confirmation.

By clicking a link it creates a new session can I can't automatically redirect the user to that protected page. I'm trying to change this by putting in a reference to the redirect inside the confirmation link. I would like to do:

```
<%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token, :redirect_to => stored_location_for(@resource)) %>
```

But I can't figure out how to get access to `stored_location_for` (or if that is even the right location to get). It is defined in [`Devise::Controllers::Helpers`](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#stored_location_for-instance_method), but it is an instance method so I can't do `Devise::Controllers::Helpers.stored_location_for(…)`.

How do I get access to `stored_location_for` or what is the better way of doing this?

My goal is to do that and then in my custom ConfirmationsController define:

```
def show
  if params[:redirect_to]
    session["user_return_to"] = params[:redirect_to]
  end
  super

end
```

That should work right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out. I'm not sure if this changes with the update Devise did yesterday in making Devise::Mailer put most of its functionality into a module. (See the [code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb) and [ticket](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/1164) for more information).

Basically it boils down to not being able to access the `session` inside of a mailer view. Therefore you have to pass the redirect as a variable. Devise uses an `after_create` method on your resource (`User` in my case) which then sends the confirmation email. This meant I couldn't just pass the session variable directly to the mailer. Thus I feel like this is a pretty nasty work-around in order to get this functionality, but here is the code:

To get the `redirect_to` variable into the mailer you have to add a variable to the user, thus:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  …
  attr_accessor :return_to
  …
end
```

Then you have to set that variable when you create the user for the first time.

I already had a custom controller setup for registration. (See Devise' Readme on how to set this up, or see @ramc's answer for direction). But it was relatively easy to do this part, I just added it to the parameters and let the rest take care of itself.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    params[:user][:return_to] = session[:user_return_to] if session[:user_return_to]
    …
    super
  end
end
```

Now the user has a variable `return_to` which is set. We just need to access that in the `confirmation_instructions` email. I've already rewritten part of confirmation_instructions.html.erb so inside there I just added:

```
<% if @resource.return_to %>
  <%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token, :redirect_to => @resource.return_to) %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %>
<% end %>
```

(For those who are new to this, `@resource` is the variable Devise uses to define your user).

Now once the user clicks on that link we need to redirect them. @ramc's `before` filter works well for this:

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  before_filter :set_redirect_location, :only => :show

  def set_redirect_location
    session[:user_return_to] = params[:redirect_to] if params[:redirect_to]
  end
end
```

That will take care of the case where a new user goes to a protected page then signs up, clicks on the confirmation link and is properly redirected to the protected page.

Now we just need to take care of the case where a user does the above, but instead of clicking on the link, they try to go back to the protected page. In this case they are asked to sign-up/sign-in. They sign-in and then are asked to confirm their email and are given the option of resending the confirmation email. They put in their email and now we need to put the `redirect_to` variable in that new confirmation email.

To do this we need to modify the ConfirmationController, similarly to how we did the RegistrationController. This time we need to modify the `create` method. The way it works out of the box is to call a class method on the user called `send_confirmation_instructions`. We want to rewrite that method so we can pass the `return_to` variable into it.

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  def create
    self.resource = resource_class.send_confirmation_instructions(params[resource_name],session[:user_return_to])

    if resource.errors.empty?
      set_flash_message(:notice, :send_instructions) if is_navigational_format?
      respond_with resource, :location => after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
    else
      respond_with_navigational(resource){ render_with_scope :new }
    end
  end
end
```

The only thing different than what comes with Devise is that first line of `create`, we pass two variables in. Now we need to rewrite that method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.send_confirmation_instructions(attributes={},redirect=nil)
    confirmable = find_or_initialize_with_errors(confirmation_keys, attributes, :not_found)
    confirmable.return_to = redirect if confirmable.persisted?
    confirmable.resend_confirmation_token if confirmable.persisted?
    confirmable
  end
end
```

`confirmable` becomes an instance of User (the current user based on email). So we just need to set `return_to`.

That's it.

Answer (score 10):

Looking at the way stored_location_for has been implemented in lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb

```
def stored_location_for(resource_or_scope)
   scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
   session.delete("#{scope}_return_to")
end
```

It is possible to otherwise access it using session['user_return_to']. In your case, you would lose that session object because when the user clicks on the link from the confirmation mail, it might be a new session that is spawned.

You can implement whatever you have suggested as a before filter:

```
class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController 
     before_filter :set_redirect_location, :only => :show

     def set_redirect_location
         session["user_return_to"] = params[:redirect_to] if params[:redirect_to]
     end
end
```

In addition to this, you will have to modify the route to make devise call your controller instead of its own confirmation controller.

```
devise_for :users,
           :controllers => { :confirmations => 'users/confirmations'}
```

Hope this helps :)

Note: The code snippets are not complete and only contain relevant details.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I like your before_filter implementation much better. I already have my custom controller worked out. And I understand that it will be two different sessions when they click the link, which is why I want to get access to it and put it in the params[] for the confirmation link. This way it will transcend sessions. But I'm having trouble with getting the url in the first place. session['user_redirect_to'] doesn't seem to work. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see from the comments in the devise source code, all you need to do is implement the following in your registrations_controller.rb:

```
def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  session["user_return_to"]
end
```